# How is a convex combination of Dirichlet-distributed variables distributed?

Tags: beta-distribution, dirichlet-distribution, sum

Let $X = (X_1, \dots, X_K) \sim \operatorname{Dir}(\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_K)$ and define the convex combination $Y = \sum_{i=1}^{K} c_i X_i$.
In the case of $K=2$, the constraint $\sum_{i=1}^{K} X_i = 1$ of the Dirichlet distribution implies that $Y = c_2 + (c_1 - c_2) X_1$. Thus, since the marginal distributions $X_i \sim \operatorname{Beta}(\alpha_i, \sum_{j \neq i} \alpha_j)$, the variable $Y$ has a Beta distribution shifted and scaled to have support $[\min_i c_i, \max_i c_i]$ (provided $c_1 \neq c_2$).

Can something similar also be said for $Y$ in the general case $K>2$?

Comment: I don't see how $Y$ can possibly have a Beta distribution unless $c_2=0.$

Comment: Would it not be a Beta distribution shifted scaled by $1/(c_1 - c_2)$ and shifted by $c_2$?

Comment: Yes: and that is not a Beta distribution.  All Beta distributions have the interval $[0,1]$ for support, by definition.